# Where to source Tapioca balls for Homemade Milk Tea?

Tags: asian-cuisine, ingredient-selection, drinks

Looking to make some bubble tea at home, not sure where to source the tapioca balls from.

Local grocery stores don't seem to have them.

Are these generally "balled" at home, or bought already in ball form?

I'm in the Toronto, Canada area.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't buy them on the web? Do you have a local "Asian" grocery store?

Comment: I suspect that what you're looking for are sold as 'tapioca pearls'.  (I can't say for sure, as I've never had bubble tea)

Comment: @Joe From a brief search, it looks like a lot of them are "boba". They are the black ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would personally go buy them at an Asian grocery or online (Amazon or something similar), but you can make them. It seems fairly straightforward if you have the tapioca powder.

[Recipe One](https://thethingswellmake.com/recipe/how-to-make-boba-tapioca-pearls-from-scratch/)

[Recipe Two](https://snapguide.com/guides/make-your-own-tapioca-pearls-from-scratch/)

Comment: Nice quote from the first link: "It took me less time to make boba tapioca pearls from scratch than it did for me try to cook the store bought boba!

Comment: @Jolenealaska Thanks for the edit-- not sure why I put arrowroot originally.

Comment: It was @Jefromi who did the edit, But I can say you're welcome for them :)