# What is the proper ratio of tapioca , sugar and water for boba?

Tags: dessert, drinks, starch

I want to make my own boba.

My first attempt turned out to misshapen flat disk. It looks more like a bread roll.

I really would like to them to be round.

I used

- 120g tapioca starch
- 78ml water
- 65g brown sugar

Might be too dry.  I cooked it 6 min on high, 20 min on medium and let it stand for 20min.

What is the proper ratio of all three ingredients?

Comment: Can you expand on your process for making boba? Recipes I've seen generally involve making a dough, forming the dough into tiny boba balls, then completing cooking. Are you just stirring everything into the pot and cooking it?

Comment: Tapioca comes in many different forms.  I always assumed boba was made with "tapioca pearls" rather than the finer ground stuff.

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/78974/67